# Firestore| RecyclerView not sorting or updating in realtime

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I have a `ChatActivity` and I can successfully send messages between two users. I want to sort the messages with a timestamp value (like your regular chat application). I have called `orderBy()` but the messages still aren't sorted. This is my code in my activity's `onCreate()` method:

```
     Query query = currentUserRef.orderBy("time", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
            FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Messages> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Messages>().setQuery(query, Messages.class).build();
            mAdapter = new MessagesAdapter(options,messagesList);
            mLinearLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            mMessagesList.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mMessagesList.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayout);
            mMessagesList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
  private void sendMessage() {
        String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
            Map messageMap = new HashMap();
            messageMap.put("messages", message);
            messageMap.put("type", "text");
            messageMap.put("time", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
            messageMap.put("from", mCurrentID);
            chat_user_ref.add(messageMap).addOnSuccessListener(documentReference -> currentUserRef.add(messageMap).addOnSuccessListener(documentReference1 -> txtMessage.getText().clear()));
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mMessagesList.scrollToPosition(messagesList.size());
        }
```

I've tried passing the RecyclerView as a parameter to my adapter and then try to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onBindViewHolder()` but I can't do that.

I want the messages to be sorted on the chat screen (from oldest to newest). And I want the recyclerview to update when a new message has been sent.

Comment: Have you solved the issue? If no, please add the way you initialize `currentUserRef` and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: Apologies, I've been traveling. But yes. I solved the issue. Thanks for checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same problem when I was developing my chat app. Setting the following attribute on the layout manager solved it for me:

```
Query query = currentUserRef.orderBy("time", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
mLinearLayout.setReverseLayout(true);
```

Comment: please use Query.DIrection.DESCENDING because from newer to older times the order is decreasing. Then setReverseLayout set to true - this inverts the way the linear layout itself presents the data i.e . if it doesn't work then this is something to do with your FirestoreRecyclerAdapter especially the way you are implementing your messageList there.

Comment: Problem was with the RecyclerAdapter. I had actually used `Query.Direction.ASCENDING` and `mLinearLayout.setReverseLayout(false)` so it's the same logic. But i fixed it just now. My recyclerView is not scrolling to the bottom after I send a message though. Any help with that?

Comment: You can add an observer to your adapter via the registerAdapterDataObserver() method passing in a new observer. Then override the observer's onItemRangeInserted() method under which you call the LayoutManager's method scrollToPositionWIthOffset(0, 1)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: No problem Alex